# Why i can't hide show my paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created some content, when click on it I want to show paragraph with class paragraphtoggle, but not working, here is what i tried.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11698/

HTML

```
<div class="enzimskiprogramindex herbaprogramindex herbaindex nomargin nopadding container-fluid produkti">
     <div class="maincontainer">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <img src="img/enzicon.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <h1 class="ffyanone">Enzimski program prihrane pcela</h1>
                    <p class="paragraphtoggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempus ultrices nulla, 
                        id consequat ipsum rutrum eget. Sed eget eros sit amet est mattis ultricies vitae ut nibh. 
                        Vestibulum vitae mi tincidunt, dapibus orci nec, malesuada eros. Duis pellentesque tincidunt 
                        quam, et dignissim dolor laoreet sed. In sed turpis ipsum. Integer elementum, orci eu ultrices 
                        facilisis, justo nisi finibus lorem, fringilla pellentesque elit tortor nec sem
                    </p> 
                </div>
               </div>       
        </div>
    </div> 
</div><!--Closed div indexproducts-->
```

JS

```
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */ $(document).ready(function () {
$(".enzimskiprogramindex").on('click', function () {

    $(".paragraphtoggle").not($(this).next(".paragraphtoggle")).slideUp();
    $(this).next(".paragraphtoggle").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paragraph is not the `next` sibling of the clicked element.

Use `find()` instead of `next()` to get the element that is inside the clicked element.

Another thing is that, to `slideUp` the other paragraphs than the clicked, use `siblings()` and then `find()` the paragraphs by the class selector and then slide them up.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/DTcHh/11704/)

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".enzimskiprogramindex").on('click', function() {

    $(this).find(".paragraphtoggle").slideToggle();
    $(this).closest(".enzimskiprogramindex").siblings().find(".paragraphtoggle").slideUp();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.enzimskiprogramindex {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #f0952e;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
.enzimskiprogramindex .maincontainer {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.produkti img {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.produkti h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
  font-size: 27px;
}
.paragraphtoggle {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  display: none;
}
.herbaprogramindex {
  background-color: #71a139;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="enzimskiprogramindex herbaprogramindex herbaindex nomargin nopadding container-fluid produkti">
  <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <img src="img/enzicon.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h1 class="ffyanone">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET</h1>

          <p class="paragraphtoggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempus ultrices nulla, id consequat ipsum rutrum eget. Sed eget eros sit amet est mattis ultricies vitae ut nibh. Vestibulum vitae mi tincidunt, dapibus orci nec, malesuada eros.
            Duis pellentesque tincidunt quam, et dignissim dolor laoreet sed. In sed turpis ipsum. Integer elementum, orci eu ultrices facilisis, justo nisi finibus lorem, fringilla pellentesque elit tortor nec sem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Closed div indexproducts-->
```

Comment: Ok thats, work but now i have 3 content for sliding, and I want when click on first to show content thats working, but when after that click on second content to hide previous content  and show second
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11702/

Comment: @RS92 Can you please check the answer, notice the `siblings()` also add complete code in the jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11702

Comment: @RS92 Check updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/DTcHh/11704/). I've also updated answer

Answer (score 2):

As paragraph `paragraphtoggle` is a descendants of div `enzimskiprogramindex`, you need to use [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

`$.fn.next()` looks from immediately following sibling.

*Use*

```
$(this).find(".paragraphtoggle")
```

instead of

```
$(this).next(".paragraphtoggle")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".enzimskiprogramindex").on('click', function () {


        $(this).find(".paragraphtoggle").slideToggle();
        $(".paragraphtoggle").siblings(".paragraphtoggle").slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/DTcHh/11700/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$(".enzimskiprogramindex").click(function(e) {
    $('.enzimskiprogramindex p').not($(this).find('p')).toggleClass("enzimskiprogramindex");
    $(".ffyanone").next("p").slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/q0kdej13/3/